# SurfaceView goes black -- MediaPlayer Android

Tags: android, media-player, surfaceview

I am using MediaPlayer and SurfaceView to stream a video from a server. The video plays fine however if the activity goes in "Paused" state, eg. when the user taps home button or recent button, On resuming the player activity the SurfaceView becomes black. I know when you leave the activity, the surfaceView is destroyed and upon resuming it is created again, so as workaround I saved the player's current position in onPause() of the activity and when the activity resumes, I seek the player to that position. This didn't work either.

**So my question is how can I make the surfaceView keep the frame/picture it was displaying when the user goes out of the activity?**

```
public class VideoPlayer extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback, OnPreparedListener {


    private long PREV_PLAYER_POS;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_videoplayer);

        mDecorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
        mediaController = new VideoControllerView(this, mDecorView);

        handler = new Handler();
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        usedURL = intent.getExtras().getString("vidURL");

        vidID = intent.getExtras().getString("id");
        mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
        mProgressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.VISIBLE);

        mContext = this;

        surfView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.videoView4);

        SurfaceHolder holder = surfView.getHolder();
        holder.addCallback(this);

        mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

        mMediaPlayerControl = new VideoControllerView.MediaPlayerControl() {
            ……
           }


        mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);


        mediaController.setOnSeekStartListener(new onSeekStartListener() {

            @Override
            public void onSeekStarted() {

            }
        });

        mediaController.setMediaPlayer(mMediaPlayerControl);
        mediaController.setAnchorView((ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.container4));
        mediaController.setEnabled(true);
        mediaController.show();


    }


    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
                               int height) {

        mMediaPlayer.setDisplay(holder);

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {

        mMediaPlayer.setDisplay(holder);


        try {

            mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(usedURL);

            mMediaPlayer.prepareAsync();

        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SecurityException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {


        surfView.requestLayout();
        surfView.invalidate();

        mMediaPlayer.start();


    }


    @Override
    public void onSurfaceViewSizeChanged(int width, int height) {


    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        mMediaPlayer.seekTo((int)PREV_PLAYER_POS);


    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();

        mMediaPlayer.stop();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();


        PREV_PLAYER_POS = mMediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();

        mMediaPlayer.pause();

    }





    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        mMediaPlayer.release();
        mMediaPlayer = null;
    }

}
```

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

Start your video in **onResume**,

```
 @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    mMediaPlayer.start();
        mMediaPlayer.seekTo(length);
}
```

Hope it ll work..

Comment: It doesn't work. PS: I don't want to start the video when the user resumes the activity. I want the player to remain in paused state

Answer (score 0):

The SurfaceView's surface may or may not be destroyed when you bring something up in front of the activity.  See [this section](https://source.android.com/devices/graphics/architecture.html#activity) in the graphics architecture document for an overview.  If it didn't get destroyed, then `surfaceCreated()` won't be called again, and your app will never call `mMediaPlayer.setDisplay(holder)` to connect the MediaPlayer to the surface.

I would guess that, if you brought up "recents" and then rotated the device, things would work when you returned (because the device rotation forces the surface to be recreated).  You may want to add some logging to the various callbacks to see when they fire.

You will need to have a static variable that tracks whether or not the surface has been destroyed (e.g. `static bool haveSurface = false`, set to true in `surfaceCreated()`, false in `surfaceDestroyed()`.  If it's true in `onCreate()`, call `mMediaPlayer.setDisplay(holder)` immediately.

[Grafika](https://github.com/google/grafika) has some examples of working with the odd SurfaceView-vs-Activity lifecycle issues, though I don't think any of them quite fit your use case.